# Javascript access json property

Tags: javascript, json

I am sending an api call and retrieving data in json format.

```
$.getJSON(weatherAPI, function(data){
  // get data
});
```

If I call the object `data` and one of its properties (`data.weather`) I get the following outputs

```
[Object {
    description: "clear sky",
    icon: "xyz",
    main: "clear"
}]
```

I can't seem to use `data.weather.description` to get the desired output of "clear sky"

The whole json format data below

[image]

Comment: for loop ``weather``

Answer (score 6, accepted):

weather is an **`array of Objects`**, so you need to specify the **`index`** and access the property

```
 console.log(data.weather[0].description);
```

if you need to print all the element's value, use **[`.foreach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** or  **[`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)**

**`.map()`** returns a new array while **`.forEach()`** doesn't. **`forEach()`** just operates on every value in the array. if you just need to console output the values use **`forEach`**.

**using forEach,**

```
data.weather.forEach((e) => {
  console.log(e.description);     
});
```

**using .map**

```
data.weather.map((e) => {
  console.log(e.description); 
  return e;    
});
```

Comment: Canonically, you'd use `.forEach()`, not `.map()`, which wastes time creating and returning an array the same length as `data.weather` that you don't even use here.

Comment: why `map`, i know it serves the purpose here, but `forEach` is advisable for this use case.

Comment: @Nemani If OP wants to return , i have added that! thanks for the headsup